# Power Calculation for GEE

Tags: sample-size, binary-data, statistical-power, generalized-estimating-equations

I have performed a rather tricky analysis of some longitudinal data and now wish to do a retrospective power calculation.

I ran a generalised estimating equation analysis for data that consisted of several covariates (some factorial and some continuous) and a binary dependent variable measured once weekly for 10 weeks. I am interested in the association of one of the continuous covariates with the dependent binary variable, and in this case there appears to be no association. I would like to just do a sanity check and make sure that my study was not under-powered.

Is there any way I can perform a retrospective power calculation for this type of analysis?

I am using R version 3 for the GEE analysis, but I'd be happy to try anything if I could solve this problem which I have been trying to get my head around for ages.

Many thanks

Ian